# Keeping track of images that are on the screen within a fading-image grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

So, I have a grid of div. Each div has a bunch of images stacked on top of each other within it. I am fading the top one out and a bottom one in randomly to make a fading effect.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
 function rotate(className) {
     // Image Size
     var suffix = " :first-child";
     var path = className.concat(suffix);
     var pathImg = className.concat(" img");

     var imgW = $(path).width();
     var imgH = $(path).height();
     $(className).width(imgW).height(imgW);

     var nImages = $(className).children().length;
     var currentImage = 0;


     setInterval(function () {

         var randomnumber;
         if (currentImage < 9 && currentImage > 0) {
             console.log(className + " is currently a city");
             randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (8)) + 9;
             if (randomnumber > 16 || randomnumber < 9) {
                 console.log("wrong number");
             }
         } else {
             randomnumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1);
             var index = onScreen.indexOf(randomnumber);
         }

         onScreen.splice(currentImage, 1);
         currentImage = randomnumber;

         onScreen.push(randomnumber);
         console.log(onScreen);

         $(pathImg).fadeOut(1000);
         var pathImgNew = className.concat(" > img:eq(" + randomnumber + ")");
         $(pathImgNew).fadeIn(1000);

     }, (Math.floor(Math.random() * (10000) + 5000)));
 }
```

Basically, what I need to do is keep track of which images are **currently visible** and prevent duplicates from being shown. The images aren't being pulled from an array of sources, just a random child from each div. Each div has the same images in it, though, and each child of each div has the same number.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hnyoLtws/2/

Basically, I need to prevent duplicates. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hnyoLtws/2/ it is showing for me

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rg19d45u/ I forked, not sure why it isn't working. What browser are you using?